# Static class Vs injection in Blazor server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am a WPF developer. I am part of a team that has developed an ERP application. I want to convert the application into Blazor Server for the web. I am new to web technology and Blazor.

We have a static class that has nearly 50 properties (only properties, no methods) to store certain data at the application level. We set these property values when the user logs in. After that, we use these values wherever they are required.

Now my question is, how can I use this class in Blazor? I have searched the web and found two ways.

1. Add a singleton service. Inject it in wherever required and use its values.
2. Use the static class directly wherever required, without service injection.

Which is the best approach in my case, and why?

Answer (score 6):

Both approaches could be "syntactically" correct but the dependency injection will give you the best flexibility. Since the transition to .NET Core, DI is integrated in the framework, so it's quite straightforward to implement it (although hard to dominate it on the beggining).

Anyway, reading your question, it seems that you pretend to store some user related data for later use. If that's the case then a **singleton** won't be the best choice here, since you're now on a multiuser environment and all users would be accessing the same instance everytime.

You should create a factory that creates that class for each user, and then register it on DI as **scoped**, since that kind of objects last all the session of the user.

Here you will find a useful doc from Microsoft about what you're trying to achieve, including patterns and practices:

[Configuration Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Best regards

Comment: You are suggesting to register Di as transient . So in this case when I inject this class then everytime it reset value so is it right to way to register as transient clasd

Comment: DI won't reset anything. What it's supposed to do is reload it from source. I've updated the answer with a link to the docs of the fundamentals and patterns for what you're trying to do. If it is useful, please mark the answer as accepted. Best regards

Comment: Thanks for link. I will check and let you know. As I have seen in Microsoft doc that transient services create new instance whenever it inject from component

Comment: Sorry... It's my fault. I shouldn't answer SO technical questions at 3 o'oclock in the morning... I mean SCOPED, not transient. Sorry again and best regards

Comment: Don't be sorry anyway thank you again for your reply. Scoped service has one problem in my case, class is reinstating whenever user reload browser